# I'm unable to reference a background image in my react index html file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm unable to reference a background image in my react index html file. I see the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/background.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I think it has something to do with my webpack.config! This is set up as follows:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  
          use: [{
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: { 
                  limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                  name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
              } 
          }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets:['react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

Does anyone know what I might need to change? Do I have to configure file-loader?

Comment: I see you are putting images in `images` folder. Also using `[hash]-[name].[ext]` as image name. Check how your `background.png` is being output.

Comment: It seems to be a server response issue though...